# Unexpected behavior of Set

Tags: evaluation, notebooks, user-interface

`Set` doesn't work in some conditions.

```
(* Input separately, whithout "()" or ";" *)

In[1]:= expr1 = x + y == 0 && x > 0
Out[1]= x + y == 0 && x > 0

In[2]:= expr2 = x + y == a && x > 0
Out[2]= x + y == a && x > 0

In[3]:= {expr1, expr2}
Out[3]= {expr1, x + y == a && x > 0}
```

Evaluating again would make the assignments successfully.

```
(* Chinese Edition *)

In[4]:= $Version
Out[4]= "10.3.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 21, 2015)"
```

I'm wondering if I have done something wrong. However, I found that *Mathematica* returned to normal behavior when I minimized the Suggestions Bar.

Any ideas?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem at all, but here's something to try: [permanently disable the suggestions bar](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12406), restart Mathematica, and try again.  Does it work now?

Comment: Well, then you have the solution.  Turn off the suggestions bar.  It's clearly a bug.  You should report it to Wolfram support.

Comment: So @Szabolcs you can reproduce it now?  A ";" also avoid it happens. Hoping more tests to confirm it.

Comment: No, I cannot reproduce it with suggestions bar turned *on* on M10.3.1 OS X.  But maybe you're on a different version of the paclet updates, who knows.  I think it's a bug that you should report.  I doubt it's because you have the Chinese version, that should make no difference.

Comment: @Szabolcs: I'd really be interested whether the number of useful suggestions the suggestion bar has ever made to any user is at all larger than the questions about misbehavior it has triggered on this site alone...